# Stopwatch Class

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Stopwatch {
    private double startTime;
    private double endTime;

public static void main(String[]args) {

}

public void stopWatch() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void start() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

} 

public void stop() {
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public long getStartTime()
{
    return (long) startTime;
}

public long getEndTime()
{
    return (long) endTime;
}

public long getElapsedTime()
{
    return (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
}

public short getMilliSeconds()
{
    return (short)((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) % 1000);
}

}
```

I need to run this testSearch with the StopWatch Class above 
When I input the array size I get the Linear Search result but the Binary Search stays at 0 nano seconds
        import java.util.*;

```
    public class testSearch {
            public static void main(String[] args){

                    // input array size from user
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter array size: ");
            int size = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            // create the array (the numbers do not really matter)
            int[] numbers = new int[size];
            for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
                // we want the numbers sorted for binary search
                // so why not just the numbers 0,1,...,size-1
                numbers[i]=i;
            }

            // store the time now
                    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            // linear search for size (which is not in the array)
            linearSearch(numbers,size);
            // display the time elapsed
                    System.out.println("The time taken by Linear Search is " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) + "nanoseconds.");

            // prepare to measure the time elapsed again
                    startTime = System.nanoTime();
            // binary search for size
            binarySearch(numbers,size);
            // display the time elapsed
                    System.out.println("The time taken by Binary Search is " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) + "nanoseconds.");
            }

        public static boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int key) {
            for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                if(a[i]==key) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static boolean binarySearch(int[] a, int key) {
            int low = 0;
            int high = a.length -1;
            int mid;
            while (low <= high) {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
                if (a[mid]>key) {
                    high = mid - 1;
                } else if (a[mid]<key) {
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the output that I get

Enter array size:

2

The time taken by Linear Search is 1456959922854 milliseconds.
The time taken by Binary Search is 0 milliseconds.

Comment: How do you get that output when your code prints "nanoseconds"?  Where did "milliseconds" come from?

Comment: @IanMc the second code i uploaded was a template that the professor gave us. We were instructed to modify it so that we can implement the first code. i forgot to change that.

Comment: I'll look into your code and get back to you.

Comment: Couple of things:  1)  You create a StopWatch() object before linearSearch, but don't start it.  The constructor alone won't start it - you have to explicitly run stopWatch.start().  2)  The stopWatch() method of StopWatch seems broken; it should update 'endtime'?  3)  Any reason why StopWatch only has milli precision, and not nano?  Both linear and binary searches run very fast, and milli precision may show 0.  4)  StopWatch should have a method that returns 'endTime- startTime'; this method should be used to calculate the search times; not getElapsedTime(). Let me know if you have questions